# What does $|f (x)|$ mean in the context of Big-O?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, data-structure

In the definition of the 'Big-O Notation', I see the following notation in [Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 8e, by Kenneth Rosen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1260091996):

$$|f (x)| ≤ C|g(x)|$$

Now I know that $|\ \ |$ stands for absolute value but does it have the same meaning in the above context as well?

Comment: Yes, it does. It the above holds for all $x$ and some $C$, then we write $f(x)=O(g(x))$

Comment: You use this often for some convergence property. If you have a function with a summand, that is $O(x)$, that summand is vanishing, when $x\rightarrow 0$.